# Meaning of BASH operators "^", "|" and "$" in condition ^(n|N)$

Tags: bash

In my script, I am trying to make "Try again? [y/N]" condition...

```
if [[ "$response" =~ ^(n|no)$ ]]; then do something...,
```

but I don't understand meaning of symbols "^" and "$" used here. I tried just simple `[[ if $response =~ (n|no) ]]` and it worked, but if I typed something like "nein" it still worked... I took pipe `(|)` as "OR" operator, but it's probably also wrong.

Could somebody explain me the meaning of whole condition? It works, but I would like to know meaning too... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

These are regular expression special characters.

`^` is an anchor for the start of string (So nothing can be before the match)

`$` is an anchor for the end of string (so nothing can be after the match)

`|` is OR as you suspected

The `=~` tells the bash extended test that the string on the right is an extended regular expression and will exit with 0 for match and 1 for anything else.

`[[ if $response =~ (n|no) ]]` is flawed as the if should be outside the brackets, but assuming that is a typo in your question it will succeed if response contains an `n` at all.  You likely want the start and end anchors so that **only** `n` or `no` will match.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that =~ is what causes the right hand side to be interpreted as a regex which causes ‘nein’ to make the test true.